# Connecting 2 routers (2 networks) with 1 Internet

Tags: networking, router, cisco-router

I have 50 Megabits Internet and I'm planning to get another router to give Internet to my friend, I want to limit 25mbs for him and 25mbs for myself I'm going to do that in a way that when I am not using the Internet he will get 50mb and when he is not using the internet I will get 50mb that's some QOS stuff that I know very well but I can only apply limit to IP addresses, will that work if I get a router and plug the cable to ethernet of second router and LAN of first router(the internet one) kind of treat the second router as pc and limit to 25mbs and the second router will have many computers connected to it and can configure DHCP etc.. but I'm a little bit confused about addresses and if there is a better way to do this.

And can a pc from second router access the admin login of first router? Can they also communicated between since they are on separate routers?

First Router

```
 Internet IP: 10.*.*.*
 Subnet Mask 255.255.255.255
 Default Gateway: 10.*.*.*
 Lan IP: 192.168.0.1
 DHCP Range: 192.168.0.2 - 254
```

The first router also has DHCP reserved address with 192.168.0.2 for the second router (will that now be than LAN IP for 2nd router also?)

Second Router

```
 Internet IP: 192.168.0.1 
 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1
 Lan IP: 192.168.1.1
 DHCP Range: 192.168.1.2 - 254
```

For more clarification please view the image attached.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdLK7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st router.**

**WAN** - connected to provider.

**LANs** - connected to 2nd router's WAN and to your PCs.

**Settings**:

WAN IP/mask/gateway/DNS - according to provider's settings.

LAN IP 192.168.0.1 mask 255.255.255.0

DHCP scope: 192.168.0.64-192.168.0.191

LAN ports set to isolated mode (if not, then your friend can access your PCs). But this also prevents the communication between your PCs. If you need in, then disable isolated mode but set firewall to allow connections from 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.1 only.

---

**2nd router.**

**WAN** - connected to 1st router's LAN.

**LANs** - connected to your friend's PCs.

**Settings**:

WAN IP/mask/gateway/DNS - 192.168.0.2/255.255.255.0, 192.168.0.1, 192.1068.0.1.

LAN IP 192.168.1.1 mask 255.255.255.0

DHCP scope: 192.168.1.64-192.168.1.191

---

Bandwidth divide (including its possibility at all) is unknown, because it is highly dependent by 1st router model.

Comment: So 192.168.0.2 is the reserved address in router 1 for router 2 to provide internet, and one thing more will router 2 be double natted, is it going to make difference? and can router 2 access router 1 login page?

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai Of course, you may set router 2 to bridge mode (act like a switch) and disable its DHCP. In that case both your and your friend's PCs will be in the same network.

Comment: I also want him to manage admin panel of router 1 so can he access that if isolated network? and if his wifi acts like a bridge can I limit bandwidth then? that all the devices connected to his wifi must use 25mb and connected to my wifi use 25mb 
it can be done if the bridge can only connect his clients to some IPS in sequence like his wifi can only assign ips from 100 to 50 to his clients and my wifi from 150 to 200.

Comment: @JavedAhmadzai *I also want him to manage admin panel of router 1 so can he access that if isolated network?* Only LAN segments are isolated. Not the router inner interface. So he can manage both routers.

Answer (score 0):

For Connection Of Two Routers By Lan Cable from LAN To LAN port of the Router. 
Assuming that you have knowledge of connecting router to pc or mobile.

**1st router = your's.**

**2nd router = your friend's.**

**Step 1**.open configuration page of **2nd** router ***i.e ( by typing the IP address 192.168.0.1 in web browsers address bar)*** enter Id and password mostly default is admin & admin respectively.

**Step 2**. after successful login into the routers configuration page find DHCP option and disable it ***i.e. (DHCP server: Disable )*** after that save settings close browser and proceed to next steps.

**Step 3**. now turn on your **1st Router** connect it to the internet. if **1st router** successfully connected to the internet. then take **LAN cable** ***i.e(assume proper length according to 2nd routers position)***  and plug one end into **LAN port** ***i.e(mostly yellow in color)*** of the **1st router**.

**Step 4**: plug 2nd end of LAN cable into LAN port ***i.e(mostly yellow in color)*** of **2nd router**.

wait for the moment you will see **2nd router** is connected to the internet successfully. ***i.e(if not connected restart both router)***.

now remains the question of bandwidth allocation. don't worry about that router is build in such way that it serves data in a manner that you both will get **EQUITY**.

Comment: Will it perform better than isolated network on the 2nd router? and can I assign the subnet to router 2 so all his client connects to some range of IP that I can limit internet on?

Comment: R1 - 192.168.0.0        | Network
        192.168.0.1        | LAN
        192.168.0.2        | Router 2
        192.168.0.255    | Broadcast
        255.255.255.0    | Subnet Mask
        192.168.0.3-254 | DHCP Range
 
R2 - 192.168.0.2        | LAN


My only concern is that if there is some way to allocate 
all clients of router 2 some specific range of IP so they don't 
mix with router 1 clients

Comment: For that, you have to use LAN to WAN method. you can find or search in youtube.